# Render HTML as image into Buffer in Node.js

Tags: html, node.js, npm

What is the easiest way to render a raw HTML string, such as:

```
<b>Hello World</b>
```

into a standard Node.js Buffer as a PNG image?

I've been searching all over npm for a module that'd let me do this, but I haven't been able to find one. They all seem to render directly into a file.

Comment: Possibly using a headless browser and its printing function. So look at `puppeteer` or similar.

Comment: @Sirko That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much! I wish you replied with an answer so I could credit you. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way to do this is to simulate a browser environment using something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer) and then use its screenshot/printing functions to create the PNG file.

Some code (after the puppeteer docu - not tested):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.setContent( yourHTMLCode );
  await page.screenshot({path: 'example.png'});

  await browser.close();
})();
```